# Will installing the Voodoo lagfix clear all my settings?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, voodoo

I want to install the Voodoo lagfix on my SGS with Froyo.  Will this wipe my settings, or can I install it without worrying about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it shouldn't have any effect on your settings or apps. [The FAQ](http://project-voodoo.org/faq) from the Project Voodoo site notes:

> **Will I lose any settings or App?**
>
> None. But some sort of backup is
>   recommended of course.

Comment: This is correct, I've done it several times with no problems.

Comment: I see.  I'm wondering if I should root and backup with titanium before installing Voodoo, or if I should install Voodoo, which roots the phone anyway.

Comment: @Nathan: That probably comes down to a matter of preference, really. I'm paranoid enough that I make backups before I do...well, anything, even though 99% of it is completely safe and benign. If you're not completely comfortable with installing without a backup first then there's certainly nothing wrong with making a backup.