# Is the Voodoo lagfix compatible with Darky's ROM?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, custom-roms, voodoo, darky-rom

My SGS has awful lag, and I'm considering my steps.

The first step I want to do is install Voodoo, because I'm under the impression that it's relatively easy and will not require my to reinstall everything on my phone (though I asked about that in a [related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/10889/344) to make sure).  If that doesn't provide the desired results, I want to flash a custom ROM.  The one I'm looking at is [Darky's ROM](http://www.darkyrom.com/).

Will I have to uninstall Voodoo before installing Darky's ROM, or can I install Darky's on top of Voodoo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default kernel (Dark Core) is derived from the Voodoo kernels, but the lagfix is disabled by default. For example, the [v9.5 description on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=814091) has the following note:

> **New Kernel >> Dark Core v1.0 inside!** I9000, I9000M, I9000T ONLY (Cappy users choose speedmod or skip kernel)
>
> Customized and built by ficeto [Team Darky Dev Crew]
>
> Based on supercurio’s latest voodoo sound 6, lagfix and color - thanks a ton, Mr. Supercurio

If you install on top of a kernel with Voodoo enabled already then you should be fine (and I don't believe it will disable it, but you can re-enable if it does). There are a handful of threads on the Darky forums that talk about some of the nuances to this, but here are a couple:

- [The Quick Start Guide - Recurrent Questions](http://www.darkyrom.com/community/index.php?threads/the-quick-start-guide-recurrent-questions.2206/) (The "Recommendations prior to flashing a ROM" section talks about lagfixes).
- [activate lagfix in 9.2?](http://www.darkyrom.com/community/index.php?threads/activate-lagfix-in-9-2.968/)
- [What is a lagfix and how to enable or disable it](http://www.darkyrom.com/community/index.php?threads/what-is-a-lagfix-and-how-to-enable-or-disable-it.3850/) (This one is kind of goofy but still helpful)

Answer (score 1):

**You should *always* disable/remove Voodoo before installing a new ROM** *except* when the ROM in question includes Voodoo as the default.

Iit appears that Darky's ROM includes a custom kernel that includes Voodoo, meaning [you don't have to disable it](http://www.darkyrom.com/community/index.php?threads/guide-final-v10-1-official-darkyrom-gingerbread-jvh-noob-friendly.3080/):

> If you have a Dark_Core / Voodoo kernel installed with lagfixes enabled and you are or v10.1 (upgrade through CWM, not Odin) then it is recommended that you don't disable your lagfixes. And you will save a lot of time (Dark_Core and Voodoo kernels are from the same family)