# Can I install Darky ROM using CWM even if I'm not coming from a previous Darky ROM?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, clockworkmod-recovery, darky-rom

I want to install Darky ROM to replace my stock Gingerbread phone.

Can I do this without Odin, using CWM, or will that only work if I have a previous version of Darky?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a working CWM or 2e recovery you can flash Darky's with it just fine from a stock ROM.  If you have a lagfix, particularly the ext2 OCLF, be sure to undo it first.  (It appears Darky's uses the Voodoo ext4 lagfix, so no need to disable Voodoo beforehand.  See [Is the Voodoo lagfix compatible with Darky's ROM?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10891/is-the-voodoo-lagfix-compatible-with-darkys-rom))

Note that your data will be wiped unless you're already using Darky's, as per [the XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=814091).

Comment: The XDA link seems to be broken...

Does the data in question include all the files on the internal sd card?

Comment: @Nathan Hmm, it is taking a while to load for me, maybe they're having server issues. In any case, it doesn't normally affect the internal SD storage. I can't guarantee you that Darky's won't screw up, but I've never had any trouble with any of the custom ROMs I've tried.  You can always back up the internal SD to your PC if you want, just a simple copy-paste.